# Tightening drive side bolt for Mavic Cosmic Elite rear wheel

Tags: wheels, maintenance, hub, rear-wheel

[image]

I have a question about this Mavic Cosmic rear wheel. I wanted to remove some play from it, so I took the rear wheel apart for that purpose. Now, when I'm putting it back together, I notice that I'm not getting it quite right.

There are two nuts at the blue arrow that can be tightened against each other, and I can adjust them properly, and they are securely fastened. But the nut at the red arrow, I can only tighten it hand-tight, if I make it too tight, the wheel doesn't spin properly. So this means that it sits quite loose on the thread.

I find this too loose, since I can imagine that this can already change when Im changing wheels. Given that the tightness of this bolt determines how much play there is, it feels like Im missing something, doing something wrong, or ... something else I don’t know..

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction!

EDIT: for clarification how I ended up at this point. While I was tightening the nut at the red arrow, I (forgot that I) still had the nut at the blue arrow in place, which caused the wheel to jam.
Removing the nut at the blue arrow and tightening nuts from drive side to non-drive side was the way to go.

Comment: This question applies to most Mavic hubs prior to the introduction of 360-degree engagement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the red end first. That side stays tight for this adjustment. **It is done with a 5mm allen key in the axle and a 17mm cone spanner from the same side**.

Adjust for play at the blue end as a secondary procedure. You will have to loosen this off first before starting from the beginning.

Red end is only for removing freehub, not for adjusment. Don't lose the washer between the hub and freehub bearings or the freehub won't be free anylonger.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried to do that, but while tightening with the 5mm allen key in the axle and the 17mm cone spanner I can easily go as far as the end of the thread on the drive side. Since there is nothing to tighten to.
Do you understand what I mean? If not, I can supply more image to the question

Comment: @zwep if it doesn't stop when the axle end is flush with the nut, probably the washer between the freehub bearing and hub bearing is missing

Comment: The axle is stepped where it enters the hub bearing on the drive side. The nut pinches the axle, hub bearing, washer and freehub bearing together tightly. If this side is not working correctly there is no point in messing around with the other side. @zwep

Comment: If you can't get the red side right, don't ride the hub until you do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I started over, made sure every component was there, and now it works fine.